# Уменьшение размера таблиц без удаления данных

Tags: sql, oracle, оптимизация

Стоит вопрос об уменьшении размера таблиц в БД, т.к. утилизация достигла пиковых значений (больше 80% сейчас).

Возможно ли "сжать" таблицы без потери данных?

---

Например, в БД осталось 10 Гб свободного места, а несколько таблиц занимают по 5 Гб. Хотел бы их "сжать" без удаления данных из таблиц.

Comment: _тк утилизация достигла пиковых значений_, какие значения вы называеете пиковыми?

Comment: И определитесь, что вы понимаете под _сжать таблицы_, это реорганизация таблицы чтобы уменьшить ее размер, или сжатие данных (compress).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Сначала попробуйте избавится от фрагментации таблицы, возникшей из-за частых DML.

Таблица для примера:

```
create table bigtab (id, val) as
    select level, rpad ('A', 200, 'X') 
    from dual connect by level<=1e6
/
create index bigtabidx on bigtab (val)
/
delete from bigtab where mod (id,2) = 0 
/

500,000 rows deleted.
```

Найдите большие таблицы таким запросом:

```
select segment_name, segment_type, tablespace_name, round (bytes/1024/1024,2) sizemb
from  user_segments
where bytes > 100*1024*1024
order by sizemb desc
fetch first 5 rows only
/
SEGMENT_NAME     SEGMENT_TYPE       TABLESPACE_NAME      SIZEMB
---------------- ------------------ ---------------- ----------
BIGTABIDX        INDEX              USERS                   247
BIGTAB           TABLE              USERS                   232
```

Теперь, перестройте таблицу влючая зависимые сегменты. Для этого надо разрешить перемещение записей внутри сегмента. Запрос выше покажет, что удалось, как и ожидалось, освобдить ~50% места:

```
alter table bigtab enable row movement
/
alter table bigtab shrink space cascade   
/

SEGMENT_NAME     SEGMENT_TYPE       TABLESPACE_NAME      SIZEMB
---------------- ------------------ ---------------- ----------
BIGTABIDX        INDEX              USERS                122,94
BIGTAB           TABLE              USERS                116,19
```